# Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 is failing to repair itself

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I'm trynig to install MVS 2017 because my previous version (2015) broke. By broke I mean it was not able to connect to the internet to check my version or something and it did not let me in. Tried googling it, found nothing.

So here I am, trying to intall MVS 2017. So far nothing but failure is being seen.

My first attempt at installing it kind of worked, it even successfuly loaded up, but had no extensions whatsoever (only Visual C++) and was unable to create any projects, the project window just kept reappearing after I finished configuring my project's settings. While installing it for the first time by the way, there were a couple of windows that popped up, they basically couldn't find the installer for Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 and some "Kits" thing.. It was something along the lines of "The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable. Try selecting the installer from some other directory", but I could find it and clicked "Cancel".

After that I tried repairing MVS with the installer. Same two windows appeared, they still can not find their installers apparently, I clicked "Cancel" like in my first installation attempt and the MVS kept repairing itself for about an hour. Then, in my installation window it said "A restart is required. If needed, any remaining setup will resume automatically after the restart".

So I went ahead and restarted my PC and tried launching MVS. Absolutely nothing changed, there are no extensions that I checked when installing.

I tried googling my error messages and other problems and I ended up doing this:

- Cleared my `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache` folder
- Installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 manually
- Changed the installation directory

Nedless to say, on my previous version of MVS I had quite a lot of extensions installed. Including the lastest version of QT, support for Unity, some other C# stuff and a buch of different extensions for C++ development.

Can somebody please give me a website where I can post my logs to or help a little with my situation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This might be helpful, Please take a look : 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d5e52eb9-98f3-4c4e-9d37-09e20d2b8d4c/failed-install-vs2017-and-link-of-solution-links-back-to-itself?forum=vssetup

Comment: Thank you a lot, offline installation could actually work. I'm gonna try doing it right now.